# Diferencias entre request y response de HTTP y request y response de un SERVLET

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de aprender la arquitectura web en java y tengo algunos conceptos que aún no logro enteder,entre ellos esta si hay alguna diferencia o si funcionan juntos o separados entre request y response de un protocolo HTTP y el request y response de un servlet de Java.Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las clases `HttpServletRequest` y `HttpServletResponse` son abstracciones que te permiten obtener información de una petición HTTP y manipular la respuesta HTTP que se generará, respectivamente.

Cuando un cliente HTTP (como por ejemplo Firefox) hace una petición al contenedor web (por ejemplo Tomcat) o a un servidor de aplicaciones (por ejemplo JBoss) ocurren varias cosas.

Una de las cosas que pasan es que el contenedor web o servidor de aplicaciones toma la petición HTTP y genera un objeto que hereda de la clase `HttpServletRequest` que contiene la información de la petición: parámetros, cuerpo y cabecera. Por otra parte crea un objeto que hereda de la clase `HttpServletResponse` y rellena alguno de los campos con valores por defecto.

Una vez tiene esos dos objetos llama al método `doGet`, `doPost`, etc. que corresponda en función de la URL de la petición y del método de la petición. A estos métodos les pasa como parámetros la HttpServletRequest y HttpServletResponse que hemos creado.

Estos métodos "callback", deben ser implementados por el programador para darle funcionalidad al servlet. Generalmente se toma la petición, y se devuelve una respuesta fruto de haberle aplicado alguna función a la entrada.

Modificando el objeto `HttpServletResponse` se puede preparar la respuesta que se quiere enviar de vuelta al cliente, estableciendo por ejemplo el contenido, el tipo de contenido, etc.

Cuando acaba la invocación del método `doGet`, `doPost`, etc. que corresponda; el contenedor web o servidor de aplicaciones genera automáticamente la respuesta HTTP basandose en el objeto HttpServletResponse que hemos modificado en nuestro método, y se encarga de enviarlo al cliente.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Prueba extends HttpServlet{  
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest pet, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String nombre = pet.getParameter("nombre");  
    res.setContentType("text/plain");  
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();  
    pw.println("Tu nombre: " + nombre);
    pw.close();
  }
}
```

En este ejemplo, si hiciesemos una petición GET a una URL parecida a `http://localhost:8080/Prueba?nombre=Pepe`, el contenedor web nos devolvería una repuesta:

```
Tu nombre: Pepe
```

En el ejemplo se ve como se toma el parámetro de la URL a partir de la petición y se genera el cuerpo de la respuesta utilizando un `Writer`.

Por lo que si hay una estrecha relación entre una petición HTTP y un HttpServletRequest y una respuesta HTTP y un HttpServletResponse. Unos son mensajes que verdaderamente se envían a través de la red, y los otros son abstracciones con las que podemos trabajar en Java para obtener datos de la entrada y modificar los datos de la respuesta.

Más info:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets.htm
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Answer (score 0):

ServletRequest representa el concepto más genérico de una solicitud. No sabe nada sobre HTTP, ya que está diseñado como un protocolo independiente. HttpServletRequest lo amplía para representar una solicitud que se comunica utilizando un protocolo particular, que es HTTP en este caso.

Es una elección de diseño tener estas separaciones de modo que podamos mejorar el contenedor de Servlet para que funcione con otros protocolos simplemente definiendo e implementando un nuevo tipo de solicitud que amplíe ServletRequest. Debido a la herencia, podemos reutilizar los códigos ServletRequest existentes y la infraestructura Servlet existente para manejar este nuevo protocolo.